# How to add calculated value to matplotlib chart legend?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, matplotlib, legend

I have the following time series data frame:

```
             Date          ID     Value     Max      Min     Mean
------------------------------------------------------------------
0      2018-11-14 11:30     1        43       45      13       38  
1      2018-11-14 11:31     1        43       45      13       38  
2      2018-11-14 11:32     1        44       45      13       38  
3      2018-11-14 11:33     1        43       45      13       38  
    ... 
134    2018-11-14 12:22     2        44       55      24       39
135    2018-11-14 12:23     2        46       55      24       39
136    2018-11-14 12:24     2        49       55      24       39
137    2018-11-14 12:25     2        51       55      24       39 
    ... 
245    2019-11-14 14:11     3        44       46      35       40
246    2019-11-14 14:12     3        42       46      35       40
247    2019-11-14 14:13     3        39       46      35       40
248    2019-11-12 14:14     3        39       46      35       40
    ...
356    2019-11-14 15:19     4        37       44      32       42
357    2019-11-14 15:20     4        37       44      32       42
358    2019-11-14 15:21     4        36       44      32       42
359    2019-11-14 15:22     4        40       44      32       42
...
```

So this data frame contains time series data, but each time series data subset is attributed to a different "ID". So there is a time series curve for ID1, a separate time series curve for ID2, and then ID3, and so on. As you can see, the time series IDs occur one after the other, meaning that first time series ID1 takes place, and then time series ID2 takes place, and then ID3, and they never overlap. And then for each time series ID, I detail the Max, Min, and Mean for that whole particular curve. And so while each time stamp has a unique "Value", each time stamp has the same Max, Min, and Mean that defines that whole particular curve.

I use the following code to plot this data frame:

```
df_grouped = df.drop(columns = ['Value'])
df2 = df_grouped.groupby(by='ID').plot(kind='line',y='Value', rot=90)
```

Specifically, this loops through my data frame, and creates a separate plot for each time series ID, with the "Value" values plotted. Right now the legend just reads "Value". What I want to do, is on the legend, also print the Min, Max, and Mean for that particular curve. For example, let's say that for this dataframe, there are just 4 time series IDs. And so I would produce 4 separate plots, each with that particular curve plotted, and with the corresponding Min, Max, and Mean in the legend for each plot. And so the first plot, would should the time series curve for ID1, with "Max: 45", "Min: 13", and "Min: 38" shown in the legend along with "Value", and then the next plot would show the time series curve for ID2, with "Max: 55", "Min: 24", "Mean: 39" shown in the legend along with "Value". How can this be done in python? I am confused about how to actually get data frame values to show up in plot legends, since they need to actually be referenced from the data frame.

Answer (score 0):

String formatting is a great way to include numbers into a string. Then, you can use that string as your legend label.

Something like `label='Max: {:d}'.format(max_value)`. Where `{:d}` indicates place an integer in the string here and the value of the integer is read from the argument of `format`, in this case `max_value`.

Comment: I tried `label='Max: {:d}'.format(Max)` and the error read: `NameError: name 'Max' is not defined`. I am not sure if there is a way to preserve the initial label `Value` with the blue line indicating that is the y-axis curve, but also add the second, third, and fourth label that is max, min, and mean.

Comment: Also I am a bit confused how python knows `{:d}` refers to the max value. Though since the max value just repeats for each ID, would I need to take the average of the max value? I am not sure how that works out.

Comment: ```{:d}``` is not the part that gives the value, it says where in the string the desired value should go. ```{}``` reserves the location in the string for a number and ```:d``` is @LostinSpatialAnalysis the format of that number (in this case ```:d``` means integer). You could leave off ```:d``` and let python automatically determine the desired format, then you would just put ```label='Max: {}'.format(Max)```. This tells python to place the value that the variable Max stores in place of ```{}```. So the argument of ```format``` should be a number or a variable.

Comment: You can view [this](https://pyformat.info/) helpful link. If I am understanding the issue correctly though, I think you need to get the maximum value from each row of your data frame and put that in the argument of ```format```.